# PHP JSON Data Formatting

Tags: php, json

I'm writing an application that takes dates and runs an SQL query and spits out JSON data. So far everything seems to be working except that using json_encode it doesn't seem that my json data is correctly formatted as I get a validation error on Json lint. The issue that I see is that after echo ","; puts a comma where it needs to after my objects it then puts one after the last which throws another error. Some how I only need it up until the last dataset...

```
echo "[";
    // Loop through the records returned.
    while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        echo json_encode($row), "\n\n";
        $date = $row['date'];
        $count = $row['count'];

            echo ",";
    }

    echo "]";
```

And this is my Json data

[
    {
        "Date": "2015-01-01",
        "Count": "150"
    },
    {
        "Date": "2015-01-02",
        "Count": "262"
    },
    {
        "Date": "2015-01-03",
        "Count": "163"
    },

]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))     
    $data_arr[] = [$row['date'], $row['count']];

echo json_encode($data_arr);
```